# Wix Bundle Installer, services not installed with success message

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

Ok this is a bit weird, I've been using a `bundle installer` for the last few months to install a set of 8 windows services. The last time the bundle installer worked was a couple of days ago. However today the bundle "decided" not to work, the logs don't seem to show anything weird and the bundle **does not throw any errors when I run it**, The bundle seems to find the msi files, runs some tasks and then reverts them, then shows a success message.

I tried this on 3 different machines and had the same result. No changes to the code, no changes to the installers it bootstraps. Manually installing each msi works just fine.

The log is as follows.

```
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i001: Burn v3.10.3.3007, Windows v10.0 (Build 14393: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\DANIEL~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\{0E22FD84-F105-4205-805B-E79B6DB9988F}\.cr\ Services Bundle.exe
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS1' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS1' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS2' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS2' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS3' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS3' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS4' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS4' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS5' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS5' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS6' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS6' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS7' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS7' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallS8' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'StartS8' to value '1'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=c:\Some\Path\Setup\Output\Bundle\Services Bundle.exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=460 -burn.filehandle.self=472 -l log.txt'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'c:\Some\Path\Setup\Output\Bundle\Services Bundle.exe'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'c:\Some\Path\Setup\Output\Bundle\'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:25]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'c:\Some\Path\Setup\Output\Bundle\log.txt'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Service Bundle 2.17.0.0'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Some Manufacturer'
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '2.17.0.0'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i100: Detect begin, 8 packages
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'VFPOLEDB', Value = 'Installed'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S1RelayServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S2SyncServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S3ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S4ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S5ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S6ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S7ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i101: Detected package: S8ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:26]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:29]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleEnvironment' to value 'fasd'
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS3' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS3' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS1' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS1' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS4' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS4' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS5' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS5' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS6' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS6' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS7' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS7' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS8' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS8' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'InstallS2' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'StartS2' to value 1
[695C:540C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleEnvironment' to value 'fasd'
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i200: Plan begin, 8 packages, action: Cache
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS1 OR StartS1' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS2 OR StartS2' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS3 OR StartS3' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS4 OR StartS4' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS5 OR StartS5' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS6 OR StartS6' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS7 OR StartS7' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i052: Condition 'InstallS8 OR StartS8' evaluates to true.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S1RelayServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S2SyncServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S3ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S4ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S5ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S6ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S7ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i201: Planned package: S8ServiceInstaller, state: Absent, default requested: Cache, ba requested: Cache, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:33]i300: Apply begin
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:34]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:35]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i361: Created a system restore point.
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:36]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\DANIEL~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\{A30ECA9C-5406-4443-B293-09D92BCBB121}\.be\Services Bundle.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}\ Services Bundle.exe'
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}, version: 2.17.0.0
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S1RelayServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{505EC689-4462-477B-A85B-5E89E360173D}v2.17.0.0\S1 Service Installer.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S2SyncServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{559B091C-59A6-4829-BC34-EB5F5117D6AE}v1.0.0.0\S2 Sync Service Installer.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S3ServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C6FA7C41-25DD-429A-8E0B-CDE5F7AE7A49}v2.17.0.0\S3 Installer.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S4ServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{F5A53B70-739A-457B-80B6-B95E5BE6D7A1}v2.17.0.0\S4 Gateway Service Installer.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S5ServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{1E487270-FB27-44E0-B84B-815466CFBF1D}v2.17.0.0\S5 Sync Service Installer.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S6ServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{F6713254-6660-4A6D-B254-3D1E7AFB10CF}v2.17.0.0\S6 Installer.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S7ServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2D028B37-DA67-46FE-9AB9-4D597FDE21B4}v2.17.0.0\S7 Sync Service.msi.
[48A4:6418][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i304: Verified existing payload: S8ServiceInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{3E76F53D-8EAC-4D2C-80B5-1443A27DB0BD}v2.17.0.0\S8 Sync Service.msi.
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i352: Removing cached bundle: {f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}\
[48A4:16A4][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{f3e3a7a0-085a-469a-8f56-b18090931367}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[695C:648C][2017-08-31T22:02:37]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

I'm using the Wix Toolset 3.9 and Visual Studio 2015 to build.

Any Wix Wizards out there that care to provide an opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebuild your bootstrapper application with the version of WiX used to build the bundle (v3.10.3 in this case). BAs are source-compatible, not binary-compatible, between WiX releases.

Comment: Is this related to a new value in the middle of an enum? I looked through the code for another answer and saw cache added infront of install. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957206/wix-setup-not-installing-when-called-from-bootstrapper/42962584#42962584

Comment: Yep, exactly, @BrianSutherland.